# How to replace an API response print?

Tags: python

```
r = requests.get('https://example/api' %headerz, params={})
arguments = r.text
jsondata = json.loads(arguments)
data = r.json() #pega a resposta da api e transforma em json
sadboi = ((data['success']).replace("True", "something"))
print(sadboi)
```

i want it to replace the response, then print the replaced response in cmd, but it gives me the following:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

and the api response is just `{"Success":"True"}`

Comment: If the API response was really `{"Success":"True"}` as you say, then you wouldn't be getting a `'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'` error. `"True"` is clearly a string, not a bool. [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've done `r.json`, rather than having a json string like

```
"""{"success": true}"""
```

You have a Python dictionary like:

```
{"success": True}
```

That means that `data['success']` will be a boolean, not a string. You can replace it conditionally if you like:

```
sadboi = "on_true" if data['success'] else 'on_false'
```

Comment: @VUDUEPRAJACU great! If this answer helped you get to a solution, consider "Accepting" it by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. This lets future readers see what answer led you to the solution.